# process.WaitForExit() stuck some times while converting latex to pdf

Tags: c#, batch-file, process

I am not able to understand what to fix for this and identify issue. Please can you help me

I have checked the issue with the help of logs but I am not able to understand how to fix this and how this get's occur some times.

```
fileName = invoiceNumber.Replace(" ", "");
  string attachmentName = invoiceNumber + ".pdf";
  string latexFilePath = Helper.InvoiceOfflineFolder + fileName + ".latex";
  string pdfFilePath = Helper.InvoiceOfflineFolder + fileName + ".pdf";
  string temp = Helper.InvoiceOfflineFolder + "sample" + ".latex";

  if (!File.Exists(latexFilePath))
  {
    File.WriteAllText(latexFilePath, latexTemplateBody);
  }

  using (Process process = new Process())
  {
    _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "In Process");
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
      WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
      FileName = Helper.LatexBatchFile,
      UseShellExecute = false,
      //Verb ="runas",
      Arguments = fileName + ".latex" + " " + fileName + ".pdf"
    };
    _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "In Process StartInfo" + startInfo.Arguments);
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "In Process Start" + startInfo.FileName);
    process.Start();
    _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "In Process WaitForExit");
    process.WaitForExit(); // PROCESS STUCK HERE SOME TIMES 
    _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "Out Process WaitForExit");
  }

  _log.LogSimple(LoggingLevel.Debug, "Pdf file path  " + pdfFilePath);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't it exactly waiting for what you're asking for? Waiting for the process to exit...

Comment: Could you please add the contents of that batch file? I guess the reason is to be found there (if at all).

Comment: I second @Fildor's comment. My own experience with using LaTeX is that a compilation run (which in my case involves running pdflatex twice, then gs to optimize the resulting PDF's file size) takes about 5 seconds for documents with a few pages. You say the process is 'stuck for some time;' how much is 'some time?'

Comment: @dumetrulo Hi, this is the service and it stuck once in 2 to 3 months approx. Service will run every 5 minutes. Not for some time. Thanks

Comment: I suggest to run a timer, and kill the process if it runs for longer than about 2 or 3 minutes, and then raise an exception (or alert administrators by other means so they can review the last LaTeX document's log file).

Comment: @Fildor - \documentclass [8pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.3in,right=0.3in,top=0.3in,bottom=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Do not indent paragraphs
\usepackage{fp} % Fixed-point arithmetic
\usepackage{calc} % Counters for totaling hours and cost
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

Comment: Your all input is appreciable.